# Is there a theory of reference and formal truth in quantum information theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

Is there a theory of reference and formal truth in quantum information theory? I.e. a "quantization" of Frege Tarski or the Typographical Number Theory (TNT) system in ["Gödel Escher Bach"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del,_Escher,_Bach).

Status today:
**qbits in quantum information theory have no meaning**
Quantum information research is creating ever-more complex quantum coherent assemblies of two-state systems that someone else might relate to something. It doesn't know and doesn't care about meaning.

**The meaning assigned to qbits is entirely outside quantum information theory**
Some user may relate the "up"-state of a certain qbit to certain fact in our classical world, perform quantum operations and relate the result to another event. The user is said to use a quantum code or a quantum information protocol in order to perform a classical task in our classical world, but faster or safer. The user doesn't care about the quantum stuff inside, and inside the box there is nobody.

**Measurement results of quantum systems are classical**
Then there are physical quantum systems that we create in the lab, which behave in a complex manner yet unknown to us. Then we observe and measure, and obtain classical information about them (everything that we can observe is classical).

**Conclusion: There is nothing new** in the way we relate the result of a quantum simulation or computation to a physical quantum system **yet**.

**But what if** a novel measeurement device would read physical quantum state coherently into a register of qbits?

i.e assume quantum coherent counters and quantum coherent A/D converters (Which to my knowledge don't exist today). Like their classical counterparts they make a digital bit array state correspond to a property of a certain object out there. It is just that quantum superposition is preserved in the process. And suddenly, we have a qbit register state with something like an objective meaning.

[ to be continued in the follow up question: Quantum information theory: Who would buy a quantum coherent counter or A/D converter? Are these even a well-defined concepts? ]

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. Are you asking for an axiomatization of QI? In that case, note that quantum information is just a subdiscipline of quantum mechanics, so this exists insofar it exists for quantum physics.

Comment: In the theories of reference in mathematical logic there is a reality to described (a mathematical structure) a symbol set and propositions made out of them. The reference relation attaches a truth value to each propsition  of course with respect to the reality. In quantum information they write I and O as if they were truth values. Obviously the content is supposed to mean something. Anyone sees the field as logic but there is not theory of reference. It's time to grow up.

Comment: There are at least approaches of constructing ["quantum logic"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic). Note, that these theories (while some are in fact Boolean algebras), are not two-valent logics. But this is a slightly different thing than axiomatizing truth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Tl;dr:** There is a theory of reference, it's called "experiments" or more precisely "how to do experiments and make sense of their results". Equivalently, it's any of the multitude of answer to "how does science infer something 'real' about nature".

**Long answer:** This is slightly off-topic, as it is ultimately about the theory of science and not physics - but the theory of science underlies physics so I think it could be discussed here.

I'm not too familiar with the terms you use (it's been a long time since I read Hofstaedter), so I'm going to define how I understand them:

First of all, you ask for an underlying system of formal truths, which I interpret as follows: I believe what you mean are a [system of definitions](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/formal%20truth) and [logical truths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_truth). This is isomorphic to requiring a mathematical axiomatization of quantum information. As quantum information is in principle a subset of quantum mechanics, I believe this is more or less equivalent to having an axiomatization of quantum physics. Do we have this? To some extent (see the [postulates of quantum physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_formulation_of_quantum_mechanics#Postulates_of_quantum_mechanics)). The postulates are the underlying axioms + Zermelo-Fraenkel+Axiom of Choice and maybe some other mathematical axioms. Together with modern mathematical logic, this tells you how to derive all mathematical (formal) truths.

This gives us a system that doesn't mean anything - it's just a mathematical structure. It has no relation with the world. Now you want to have a [theory of reference](http://www.britannica.com/topic/analytic-philosophy#ref843283), which assigns meaning to definitions (at least that is what I think you want). I can't explain the details, but this is exactly what experiments and phenomenology do and it's by no means a simple business:

For example, in your theory, you might describe something like a "particle" with a "spin". Now you need to describe an experiment, where you perform preparations and a number of measurements and according to the outcome, you can map the definitions of your theory to experimental results. In a sense, an experiment is a proposition and doing an experiment is assigning a truth value to the propositon. The theory is good if it assigns the correct truth values to most or all experimental propositions. The problem arises that it is often not so easy to actually formulate the correct proposition underlying an experiment in the language of a theory...

The statement "An electron with spin up" might get it's "physical truth value" from a number of experiments that a) confirms we have something that can be described by an electron b) uses a Stern-Gerlach experiment to differentiate two orientations of spin and c) defines one of them as "up". This is how you get truth values to quantum theory (in a sense). The above is a severe simplification, because the theory is not created in the void, but it is created with a constant interaction between theorists and experimentalists. Showing that it makes sense to call something an "electron" and to describe it by a mathematical structure of the kind we use to describe the electron is by no means simple (insofar it makes sense at all - see the problems of [the concept of particles in QFT](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/quantum-field-theory/#Part)). It gets even worse if you describe effective theories - and the two-level system is an effective system.

Now you specifically ask for quantum information. From the comment, it seems you think along the following lines: In QI, we have things called "qubits" and we measure them to get "1" or "0". Sometimes, depending on the outcome, we determine some result (e.g. a computation or a message). Therefore, the "1" and "0" must "mean" something, they seem to be "truth values". However, this is a severe misunderstanding: The "1" and "0" are not truth values, they are measurement results of a two-level physical system. You could work with three-level systems (qutrits) and then measure three values - let's call them "bla", "blabla" and "blub". And thus you lose the direct connection to "truth values" - although you could of course change the underlying logic. Of course, by the way of linking the theory to experiments, you HAVE a theory of reference to infer truth values for "propostions" like "The spin of the electron is up" or "The qutrit is in the 'bla'-state", however, this is already given by quantum physics and is in no way particular to QI.

The way we assign "meaning" similar to the sense you seem to want is by an information protocol. A protocol describes how you can use the system to do a task. Let's work by example: I want to communicate with my friend on the other side of the earth. In that case, the protocol tells me how to encode my message into a quantum system and it tells my friend how to interpret the measurements (1s and 0s if we use qubits and map the results to 1s and 0s) to decode my message. In other words, this boils down to the question of how to infer meaning from language, which is not physics anymore and where there is a number of systems of reference in philosophy.

Comment: This is a good starting point. I tried to put this in my own words on https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-theory-of-reference-and-formal-truth-in-quantum-information-theory/answer/Ivo-Knittel  At some later point I will add what I am actually up to. Thank you.

Comment: @IvoKnittel: Thanks for letting me know. If you have any more questions, please ask, but I think you got my main point. If you found the answer somewhat useful, you can also upvote it.